# How to send some info/variable from post to contact form page as default value?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I have wordpress post with product details. Now i need to send id, title of product to contact form page as default value. How can i do it?

Comment: You want to add it on specific product page?

Comment: Have a look at this link. https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi If your using contact form 7 plugin you want to sent a product title on form page.

Please check below code and Also Please install below plugin for the same.

```
Plugin name - Contact Form 7 Get and Show Parameter from URL

PLugin URL - https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-get-and-show-parameter-from-url/
```

Add belwo code in the contact form page

```
</div>
    <?php $panme = urldecode($_REQUEST['pname']); ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $panme; ?>" id="pnamep" />
</div>
```

Then add below script end of form page.

```
<script>  
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("prodnafield"); 
  x[0].style.display ="none"; 
</script>
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['pname'])){ ?>
<script> 
  var z = document.getElementsByClassName("pronamet"); 

  x[0].style.display ="block"; 
  z[0].value = document.getElementById("pnamep").value; 
  console.log(z[0].value);
  z[0].disabled=true; 
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Create a text field oin conatact form 7 to get this hidden field in your form.

Check below code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group"><section class="prodnafield">
            <label class="labelnew">Product Name:</label><label class="">[getparam pname]
            [text ProductName class:form-control class:pronamet]</label></section>

        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

You will get the field in conatct form just pass the url form product page to conatact form page as

```
http://www.example.com/conatct_form_page/?pname=your_product name
```

You will Get the field on your contact form page as non editable field.

I hope this will help you.